# Dynamically Update UILabel in a Background Thread - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to dynamically update the UILabel in a loop function that is running in the background. From what I've read, you can't update the UI in the background thread, but instead only in the main. I've added the dispatch_async to my loop function, but still only get the last word of the input string to display.

Here's my simplified code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseString("Hello World")        
}

func parseString(sentence: String) {        
    var wordArr = sentence.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    for i in 0...wordArr.count-1 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        {
            self.label.text = wordArr[i]
        })
        }
    }    
}
```

`

Comment: `but still only get the last word of the input string to display` Of course, because you're assigning the new text to the label *in the loop*. So it gets changed wordArr.count times and you only see the last one, because each one replaced the previous one.

Comment: What makes you think your loop is running in the background?  `viewDidLoad` will typically be called on the main thread.

Comment: You code runs on the main thread because you dispatch_async on the main queue which is not "background" - it's still the main thread. Still, what is the question? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood a couple things. Your code is 100% running on the main thread, as you never dispatch to a background thread and even if it was, you'll never see the label display "Hello" and then "World" as it won't be re-drawn on the screen until the next iteration of the run loop, by which time the text willl already be set to "World".

Comment: Maybe use NSOperations? Add your background blocks to an asynchronous NSOperationQueue and add main thread operations, such as UILabel updates to the main queue, {NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()}.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite of your method that might or might not be what you want but it shows logic for sharing work between threads and also giving the UI time to display partial results before over-writing them.

```
func parseString(sentence: String) {
    var wordArr = sentence.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) { () -> Void in
        for i in 0..<wordArr.count {
            let seconds = UInt64(i * 2)
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.label.text = wordArr[i]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Relying on timing for race problems is never a good call, if you want to wait you should use a semaphore. Or define the variable so that it does not get overwritten.

Comment: As the global queue is shared, you shouldn't be sleeping it. You should either use your own private queue, or use `dispatch_after` (`dispatch_after` would be better in this case, as there's simply no need to sleep a thread).

Comment: Fair enough but the point of the sample was to quickly demonstrate why the OP wasn't seeing expected behaviour.